# Installing Laravel in a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, routes

I've been searching around for an answer to this and can't find anyone with my exact problem and was hoping someone else has had this issue.

I had Laravel installed locally using a vhost, and it was installed at the root. I've now had to move this install to another server at `http://domain.com/~username`, all my files are in `/~username/` and I'm using `.htaccess` to access the `public` folder from `http://domain.com/~username`.

I've also set my paths correctly and my site URL in `app.php`.

Everything almost works except for my routes.

If I navigate to `http://domain.com/~username` I get a `NotFoundHttpException`

This is my route for my homepage:

`Route::get('/', function() { ... });`

if I change it to

`Route::get('/~username', function() { ... });`

it shows me the homepage. This isn't exactly ideal and kind of hacky, plus there's a lot more issues than just the homepage.

I'm having other issues with pretty much everything because **Laravel thinks it's installed in the root folder**, and not `/~username/`.

My question is **how can I get Laravel to see that it's installed to `http://domain.com/~username/` and NOT `http://domain.com/`?**

**EDITS: adding .htaccess files**

My current .htaccess file in root (/~username)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /~username/

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /public/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

and the .htaccess file in /public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /~username/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What web server does your site use?

Comment: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer because I saw that your question was including `~username` in the path.

Comment: So in the end, are you wanting your username in the url or are you just trying to make sure that when you go to `http://domain.com/` you're taken to the public folder in your `~/username/projectname/` folder?

Comment: This is a university server so I dont have access to anything at `http://domain.com`, only my `~username` directory. I want the public folder to be accessible at `http://domain.com/~username`. I don't want people to have to visit `http://domain.com/~username/public` to view the site. I have this semi-working except for the issues with routes (Route::get().. and so on) and URLs (url(), URL::to() etc.) starting from the root, instead of beginning with `/~username/...`

Comment: Ok, I'm with you now. Can you post the .htaccess file that you're using for your university server?

Comment: Edited and added them to the question

Comment: Blergh, I'm not versed enough in .htaccess customization to be a lot of help on this one. I think you're on the right track with the htaccess redirect to your user folder's public folder and then trying to include the username in the path once the server hit's the public folder, but I'm not sure how to suggest fixing it. You may try exploring an htaccess redirect generator site like http://www.htaccessredirect.net/. Just be sure to keep a backup of your original htaccess files so you can roll back if you need. Hopefully someone else here will be able to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I might not have understood your question properly but here is my solution.

Go to /bootstrap/paths.php and change to:

```
return array(
    'app' => __DIR__.'~username/../app',
    'public' => __DIR__.'~username/../public',
    'base' => __DIR__.'~username/..',
    'storage' => __DIR__.'~username/../app/storage',
)
```

I'm not sure if this will work.  I haven't tried it.